# How to create feature with condition by using where()?

Tags: python, pandas

I am encoding my categorical data in column "Gender" by get_dummies()
[Data at begining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s7n6.png) 
Next, I have to create new feature isMale by using where()
This feature should show gender by value(0 and 1), if gender is "female" than isMale equals to 0, and analogical gender="male" than isMale=1

And this feature should swap my "Gender" or just concatenate to my dataset

I don't get how to use where() method for creating feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace your gender column:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df['Gender'] = np.where(df['Gender'] == "Male", 1, 0)
```

To add a new column:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df['isMale'] = np.where(df['Gender'] == "Male", 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need np.where. since you're assigning boolean value, just check if Gender= Male is True or False, then convert True/False to int will get you 0 and 1

```
df['isMale'] = df['Gender'].eq('Male').astype(int)
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but my main task wants using where() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use assign and then the np.where

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

...


df = df.assign(
    isMale=np.where(df['Gender'] == 'Female', 0, 1)
)
```